# Eating pork intentionally

Tags: tawba, pork

May Allah forgive me for this but I cant sleep. I was in a ramen place with my friend and I was really curious about the broth taste and it was pork broth and I sipped it n then spit it out. I’m so ashamed that I let myself get weak over this. Will Allah forgive me and will my prayers be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

**Sincere tawba is always accepted by Allah. Allah says:**

- Verily, He is One Who forgives (accepts repentance), the Most
  Merciful.
  Quran, Sura 2 (Al-Baqara), ayah 37[20]

> Shirk is an unforgivable sin if one dies without repenting from it
> Indeed, Allah does not forgive associating others with Him in worship,
> but forgives anything else of whoever He wills. And whoever associates
> others with Allah has indeed committed a grave sin. Quran, Sura 4
> (An-Nisa), ayah 48[25]

**As you have not performed shirk, be hopeful ask forgiveness from ALLAH. He love's all his persons more than 70 times of their own mother. He will not leave us in trouble, he will must forgive "JUST KEEP FAITH"..**

As such, becoming hopeless of the mercy of Allah is prohibited. The Quran declares:
Say: "O my Servants who have transgressed against their souls! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah: for Allah forgives all sins: for He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.

Quran, Sura 39 (Az-Zumar), ayah 53[26]
Again, God says to the believers in a Hadith Qudsi:[27]

"O son of Adam, so long as you call upon Me, and ask of Me, I shall forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind. O son of Adam, were your sins to reach the clouds of the sky and were you then to ask forgiveness of Me, I would forgive you. O son of Adam were you to come to Me with sins nearly as great as the earth, and were you then to face Me, ascribing no partner to Me, I would bring you forgiveness nearly as great as it."[27]

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repentance_in_Islam#:~:text=The%20Quran%20declares%3A,Oft%2DForgiving%2C%20Most%20Merciful.&text=%22O%20son%20of%20Adam%2C%20so,and%20I%20shall%20not%20mind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repentance_in_Islam#:%7E:text=The%20Quran%20declares%3A,Oft%2DForgiving%2C%20Most%20Merciful.&text=%22O%20son%20of%20Adam%2C%20so,and%20I%20shall%20not%20mind.)

Comment: "Indeed, Allah does not forgive associating others with Him in worship, but forgives anything else of whoever He wills."... This means Qadianis will go to Jannah?

Comment: @Ghz...
Read full & get meaning from full .... 

"And whoever associates others with Allah has indeed committed a grave sin".

Comment: You seem not to understand.. Qadianis don't associate anyone with Allah, they believe in Allah! So according to your answer, they must be going to Jannah eventually...

Comment: @Ghz... look you cannot relate every thing with each other.. 

this is the translation of verse 48, sorah Nisa.

Comment: @Ghz... , here we're putting the references of sincere Tawba, which is acceptable or not. 

Who ever returns towards ALLAH with sincere Tawba ALLAH accept him... 
This is ALLAH's rule.

Comment: If you say about Qadyani... they're the people who doesn't accept Hazrat Muhammad SAW as last prophet. So they're not accepting ALLAH's words... 

In Quran it is clear that Muhammad SAW is the las prophet. 

So please don't relate things with each other.

Comment: Just like Qadianis are not accepting Allah's word by rejecting Muhammad() as the last Prophet... Similarly, the one who has asked the question is rejecting Allah's word by eating Pork!! They both are the same!

Comment: No this is different. Any how just tell what you say, if some Qadiyani come to you and say I want to return back to ALLAH & I accept all my sins?